# Can you see your groups and pages in the Facebook for Android application?

Tags: facebook

I just received my mobile (Samsung Galaxy S) this week, so I'm really just playing around with it and the various applications.

On facebook for Android: is there a way to see your groups and pages ? You can see and type messages, see your profile and your inbox, but I can't seem to find the groups I can see on the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Facebook for Android does not currently support groups and pages.  Try accessing these features via http://m.facebook.com or http://touch.facebook.com